# How to set properties of a custom UITypeEditor using Attributes

Tags: c#, .net, uitypeeditor

Out of curiosity, imagine that you have such a UITypeEditor:

```
public class CustomEditor : System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor
{
    public bool DoSomething { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

And you want to use it to edit one of your properties with `DoSomething` set to `true`:

```
public MyClass
{
    [EditorAttribute(typeof(CustomEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

How do you specify a value for the `DoSomething` property of `CustomEditor` to be set when instanciating the editor? 
Is this possible at all or do you have to create as many classes inheriting `CustomEditor` as the number of possible configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your implementation of [UITypeEditor.EditValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yezs56kx(v=vs.110).aspx) you can look at the `context` argument to get a reference to the descriptor of the property that is being edited. You could then look at *another* attribute in which you put the editor configuration values.

```
public class CustomEditor : System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor
{

   public override object EditValue(
       ITypeDescriptorContext context,
       IServiceProvider provider,
       object value)
   {
       var property = context.PropertyDescriptor;
       var config = (MyConfigAttribute)
           property.Attributes[typeof(MyConfigAttribute)];
       // ...
   }

}
```